# Laravel 5.4 with Semantic UI React

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel-5.4, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I made few designs with Semantic UI and now I am trying to build a project with Laravel 5.4 + Semantic UI React. Maybe someone can explain me how to configure Laravel 5.4 for Semantic UI React?

Laravel official site: https://laravel.com/
Semantic UI React official site: https://react.semantic-ui.com/

Answer (score 3):

Semantic-React is just a front-end , you can  use any front-end library with laravel. For an example vuejs(another front-end library) comes pre-bundled with laravel , and there are few examples in the documentations .

Refer to 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/frontend

Comment: Yes, I know Semnatic-React is just a front-end framework. I found that in laravel official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix So maybe I must declare it in webpack.mix and then use it?

Comment: Yes , react support is built in. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#react